# Replacing Row in Data Frame with Named Character Vector

Tags: r

I'd be shocked if there's not a simple solution to this that's going to make face palm like a champ.

I'm building a DF of colors to make a network graph file. As the user interacts with the GUI, certain rows are changed to correspond to certain edge and node colors.

Here's a minimal example:

```
node_col_1 <- c(red=0, green=153, blue=255, alpha=1)
node_col_2 <- c(red=163, green=160, blue=25, alpha=1)

test_colors <-
t(
  sapply(
    seq_len(5),
    FUN= function(x) node_col_1
  )
)
```

So test_colors is:

```
red green blue alpha
[1,]   0   153  255     1
[2,]   0   153  255     1
[3,]   0   153  255     1
[4,]   0   153  255     1
[5,]   0   153  255     1
```

Then, attempting to replace rows 2 and 3:

```
> test_colors[c(2,3), ]<- node_col_2

     red green blue alpha
[1,]   0   153  255     1
[2,] 163    25  163    25
[3,] 160     1  160     1
[4,]   0   153  255     1
[5,]   0   153  255     1
```

This replaced it column wise (in the flattened df) and not row wise. Is there a simple way to do this replacement?

Comment: What you have there is not a data.frame. It's a matrix.

Comment: Ah. That would be a major issue with all of my first attempts. \*facepalm\*

Answer (score 1):

Whamp Whamp. I figured out a simple way. Wrap it in a matrix first....

```
> test_colors[c(2,3), ]<- matrix(node_col_2, nrow = 2, ncol =4, byrow = TRUE)
> test_colors
     red green blue alpha
[1,]   0   153  255     1
[2,] 163   160   25     1
[3,] 163   160   25     1
[4,]   0   153  255     1
[5,]   0   153  255     1
```

Comment: Also `test_colors[c(2,3), ] <- rep(node_col_2, each=2)` should work.